# Varying data about solubility of sodium acetate trihydrate

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility

I recently looked up the solubility of sodium acetate trihydrate in water at 20°C and found surprisingly diverse values such as:
613g/l ([GESTIS-Stoffdatenbank](http://gestis.itrust.de/nxt/gateway.dll/gestis_de/010760.xml?f=templates$fn=default.htm$3.0))
762g/l ([TU Freiberg](http://www.geo.tu-freiberg.de/Hauptseminar/2008/Daniel_Oriwol.pdf))
1250g/l ([applichem, a vendor](https://www.applichem.com/shop/produktdetail/as/natriumacetat-trihydrat-ibiochemicai/))
612g/l ([German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natriumacetat))
1233g/l ([English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_acetate))
I also found 408g/l somewhere but I can't find the source anymore.

As those values differ by a huge amount, I wanted to ask if someone knows how it comes to such a big difference.

Furthermore, I would be very grateful if someone could point out the correct value.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the ability of sodium acetate to easily form supersaturated solutions, making experimental determination of solubility tricky. -1 for not comparing Wikipedia articles in all the languages (just kidding:) ).

Comment: The ability to form supersaturated solutions was my first assumption too but shouldn't it be possible to get more exact results than "Somewhere between 408 and 1250 g/l"? That's a pretty wide range. By the way, I also searched the Latin Wikipedia which (sadly) didn't have an article about sodium acetate.

Comment: @GreenSmurf I briefly checked some other resources and it seems like there is also a confusion between the the solubilities for the anhydrous substance and its hydrate. But yeah, this is indeed an interesting question.

Comment: CRC Handbook 2017 lists same solubility values for sodium acetate and sodium acetate trihydrate: $\pu{50.4 g/100 g \ce{H2O}}$ at $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$.

Comment: seems like mixture of two factors. 1) solubility of the salt changes with temperature rather significantly 2) some values actually are for anhydrous salt.

Comment: My own experiments have given me a value of 620g/l which seems reasonably close to 613g/l and 612g/l.